# Issues with exporting SVG from blender with overlapping faces

Tags: svg, blender, adobe-illustrator, inkscape

i'm having issues with SVG Freestyle Export from blender.
[3D Scene in blender](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N2jbz.png)

[Fills issues](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eSgrT.png)

I have a problem regarding strokes that do not stop when they intersect with the face of another object. I can address this issue by using booleans, but it forces me to flatten all my geometry nodes.

[Previsualisation in blender](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vCupT.png)

This is more serious concerning filling shapes; it doesn't seem to consider depth and renders the filling shapes randomly."
Have you ever experienced something similar ?
Thanks for your help ! I'm out of idea.

Comment: Please ask this question on graphicdesign.stackexchange.com.